# ASP.NET Core 2.0: resource namespace not visible

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to make an ASP.NET Core 2.0 application multi-language. I created a resource file under a folder "Resources" called "Resource.it.resx". I set its access modifier to Public and its Namespace to Resources.

After (re)building the solution I cannot see this namespace in the C# code now in the cshtml code.

Is there some other steps to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you need to take into account:

1. Only a `Resource.resx` generates a namespace, culture-specific resources such as `Resource.it.resx` does not generate a namespace. This is the intended behavior.
2. ASP.NET Core's localization practices suggest not to use resources directly, but rather find the localized strings using `IStringLocalizer`.

I suggest you to read the fundamentals of ASP.NET Core localization [in the official MSDN guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization). There you will find examples for localizing strings in Controllers, Views and wherever you need them.

Answer (score 1):

First thing check if your resource namespace is visible in controller,
like Resources.Resource.

I had not and in this situation I have created emtpy resource class, ex. my resources name is ServiceResources.en-US.resx, in same folder I have ServiceResources.cs empty class too.

Check if you have imported your namespace in _ViewImports.cshtml correctly, with IStringLocalizer class.